# Webpack/Vue.js: new Image in js get's absolute path instead of relative one

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue-loader

In the components folder, I group components including shared assets in separate folders:

```
src/
--- components/
------ ComponentGroup/
--------- assets/
------------ img/
--------- Component1.vue
--------- Component2.vue
--------- index.js
```

Now when I load images from the assets/img folder from the template tag or the style tag, webpack/vue-loader gets the right image with a automatic relative path.

But for example when I create an Image object from javascript it uses the absolute path:

```
const img = new Image;
img.src = 'assets/img/picture.png';

http://localhost/assets/img/picture.png
```

How can I make it load the relative one? Do I have to configure webpack or do I have to use a path webpack provides for me?

The solution was using require to get the path:

```
const img = new Image;
img.src = require('.assets/img/picture.png');
```

Edit 1: I think even if I put them to the root assets folder it wouldn't get loaded/integrated to the build.
Edit 2: a require() solved it, it returned the generated path for the image.

Comment: Maybe try using `./assets/img/picture.png`.

Comment: Didn't work either, I had to use a require and it would give me the path to the image.